# Blazor WebAssembly Logging is not honoring SetMinimumLevel

Tags: logging, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application created directly from template, and I have added logging procedures as described in [Blazor WebAssembly Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-webassembly)

I have added the line builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel in my class Program, method Main

```
public class Program
{
    const string serverHttpClientName = "GoodSales.ServerAccessApi";

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;

        // JMA: Configure logging
        builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
```

NOTICE: I have no added specific logger, because navigator console log is enough for me.

Then, I have added logging in my razor component

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@using GoodSales.Services
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
@inject ILogger<NavMenu> logger;
@inject ILoggerProvider LoggerProvider
```

And added testing line in the initialization method

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {

      logger.LogDebug("LogDebug test");
      logger.LogInformation("LogInformation test");
      logger.LogWarning("LogWarning test");
```

But, in the navigator console I only see the LogInformation and the LogWarning, but not the LogDebug.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.WebAssembly.Logging.Console/) In my project it logs Debug messages as well when correctly configured. It works always because using `Console.WriteLine()` See [docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/WebAssemblyHostedLogging.md).

```
using Blazor.WebAssembly.Logging.Console;

...

builder.Logging.AddBrowserConsole()
    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug) //Setting LogLevel is optional
    .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Information); //System logs can be filtered.
```

**NOTE**: in .NET 5 Blazor Web Assembly apps (NOT in Server side) if you use standard logging it will log to Browser console automatically. However **it is possible your Browser is filtering out some logs**. It means if you are not enabling "Verbose/Detailed" logging probably won't see `Debug` and `Trace` logs. Check your settings.

In **Chrome** it is here:
[image]

**All above mentioned works only for Blazor Web Assembly (client side) Apps**. If you want to **log from a Blazor Server hosted app to your Browser console**, then it is only possible with 3rd party tool. Use [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Server.Logging.Console/) which will do the "magic". It works by sending logs from your server via SignalR channel to the user's Browser and logging to the console. Since it requires somewhat complex setup recommend to follow [this detailed docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/ServerHostedLogging.md).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in knowing the reason. Am I doing something wrong? Or the core logging component is buggy?

Comment: Your code looks good. Browsers tend to filter out debug logs since it can be lots of messages. So check your browser settings and disable log filtering.

Comment: Thanks! I'm ashamed, it was so obvious! Thank you for spending your time with this!

Comment: No problem I run into the same issue. Even wrote a console logger package to solve this by ignoring log levels. Later noticed .NET 5 Blazor logs to browser console automatically and I just have set my Browser settings :) so I worked hard for nothing...